# How to type inside redactor editor using selenium IDE

Tags: html, selenium, ide

The html structure of the redactor editor looks like:

```
<div class="redactor_text redactor_optional redactor_editor" contenteditable="true" dir="ltr" style="height: 373px;">
  <p>dummy text​</p> //Here is where the text written inside the editor goes
</div>
```

So to write inside the redactor editor I need to append text inside the `p` tag. I am unable to find a way to do this using Selenium IDE. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution to this problem:

```
<td>runScript</td>
<td>$('#editor').html('text that you want to put there');</td>
<td></td>
```

This works for our html which looks like this:
id="editor" class="wysiwyg-editor" contenteditable="true" style="overflow:scroll; max-height:300px">test

Comment: <td>runScript</td>
<td>$('.redactor_editor').html('text that you want to put there');</td>
<td></td> ---> Worked perfectly :) Thanks.